# зачем две скобки вместе в конце кода?

Tags: java

java зачем в конце блока `});` стоит фигурная и круглая вместе  вместе?

```
addMouseListener
(
  new MouseAdapter() 
  { 
    код 
  }
);
```

вызов метода операции в скобках выполняются раньше что ли я так это понимаю?

Comment: Они не стоят вместе. Они каждая закрывают соответствующую открывающую скобку.

Comment: exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

Comment: тело метода закрывается фигурными скобками а ту та   }); круглыми ?

Comment: Вчитайтесь в комментарий @Эникейщик - каждая закрывающая скобка имеет парную открывающую. Напишите их на разных строчках с отступами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну как-то так:

```
addMouseListener
( // открываются скобки, заключающие между собой список аргументов для вызова метода
  new MouseAdapter() 
  { // открываются скобки блока инициализации объекта после вызова конструктора
    код 
  } // инициализация закончена, блок инициализации закрывается
); // перечисление аргументов закончено, закрываются скобки конструкции вызова метода
```

Comment: aa_talanin спасибо большое вы объяснили доходчиво и четко спасибо )))

Comment: @сержсворовский, если хотите отблагодарить - примите ответ галкой слева :)